# If $A \subset Y \subset X$ with $A'\subset X$ and $A = A' \cap Y$, then $A = A'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $A \subset Y \subset X$ with $A'\subset X$ and $A = A' \cap Y$, then $A = A'$

Is the statement in the title correct?  I don't think so, but my attempt seems convincing it is:

$$\begin{align}A = A' \cap Y &\implies Y-A ~{= (Y-A') \cup (Y -Y)  \\= Y -A'} \\ & \implies Y-(Y-A) = Y-(Y-A') \\ & \implies A = A'\end{align}$$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You're right, it's not true. Consider $A^\prime = A \cup \{ x \}$, where $x \notin Y$. I haven't spotted where exactly your mistake is yet, but I suspect you are implicitly assuming $A = A^\prime$ somewhere in your argument...

Comment: Thanks. I have been looking at this for half an hour and shamefully must admit that I did not find the mistake. Note that I used the identity $A-(B \cap C) = (A-B) \cup (A-C)$

Comment: The equation $Y-A=(Y-A')\cup(Y-Y)$ isn't right.

Comment: In general, once you have a counterexample, like the one in the comment by @TheoreticalEconomist, you can just plug it into your computation and see where things go wrong.  To make things really easy, use $X=A'=\{1\}$ and $A=Y=\emptyset$.

Comment: Isn't $A$ a proper subset of $Y$? I.e. $A \ne Y$?

Comment: For the first part, I get
$
Y - A = Y \cap A^c
= Y \cap (A' \cap Y)^c
$
which gives
$
Y \cap (A'^{\, c} \cup Y^c)
$
to distribute to
$
(Y \cap A'^{\,c}) \cup (Y \cap Y^c) 
= (Y - A') \cup \phi
= Y - A'
$.
I'm not sure this is right but I can't see an error.

Comment: For the second part, I think that $Y - (Y - A) = Y - (Y - A')$ gives us $Y \cap A = Y \cap A'$ but I'm not sure that we can conclude from there that $A = A'$.

Comment: $Y\smallsetminus (Y\smallsetminus A) = Y\smallsetminus (Y\smallsetminus B)$ does indeed **not** imply that $A=B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that$$ Y \setminus A = Y \setminus A^\prime ,$$ so that  $$ Y \setminus (Y \setminus A) = Y\setminus (Y \setminus A^\prime) . $$

However, expanding the left-hand side:

$$ Y \setminus (Y \setminus A) = Y \cap (Y \cap A^c)^c = Y \cap (Y^c \cup A)= Y \cap A.$$

Similarly, the right-hand side is $Y \cap A^\prime$.

In other words, you've proven that $$ Y \cap A = Y \cap A^\prime, $$ which is true. However, this does not imply that $A=A^\prime$.

Comment: I see my mistake now. I implicitely assumed that $A' \subset Y$ which is not given..

Answer (score 0):

Well $Y\smallsetminus (Y\smallsetminus A) = Y\smallsetminus (Y\smallsetminus A^\complement)$ does *not* imply that $A=A^\complement$, only that $Y\cap A^\complement = Y\cap A$, which you already knew, redering the 'proof' moot.

Also...

---

Assume $A=A^\complement\cap Y$ .   That means every element of $A$ is an element of $A^\complement\cap Y$.   However, no element of $A$ can be an element $A^\complement\cap Y$.   Thus $A$ is empty.   This means $A^\complement\cap Y$ is empty too, which mandates that $Y$ is empty also (since $Y=(A^\complement\cap Y)\cup(A\cap Y)$.)

$$A=A'\cap Y ~\to~( A=\emptyset~\wedge~ Y=\emptyset)$$